# General/Phalcon - ACL and Database Storage

Tags: database, security, caching, acl, phalcon

**Background**

I'm currently working on a Phalcon application. The application itself is relatively simple, but I am using it as a tool to learn about some more advanced concepts and techniques.

I've ditched my homebrew ACL (access-control list) solution, and plumped for the ACL provided in Phalcon.

This question is more conceptual, as I would feel confident in implementing any solution.

**Question**

The question is this:
"Where do you store the information on your ACL?"

**Possible Solution**

I currently have a static array, that I fill up with the various actions and the access level of them.

I feel that this is slightly limiting, and would potentially be better served, through a database storage.

I could use a bitmask, to indicate the user roles that are allowed access to the various resources, or maybe a minimum level.

The other problem I have, is that it is hierarchical (to an extent) but multiple roles could exist - with slightly different permissions.

```
eg. 
Admin has all roles of captain, secretary and user.
Captain has all the roles of a user and the ability to pick players.
Secretary has all the roles of a user and contact the opponent's secretary.
Captain and secretary both have the ability to email players.
```

Imagine it as somewhat of a *Venn diagram* of permissions, if you will.

**Caching**

The next issue, would be that the accessing of the database every time, would add a performance overhead, so I guess caching it would make sense.

The issue would then come, how to invalidate the cache (there are only two hard things in computer science...)... maybe there could be a database field that had an md5 hash of the ACL, which was checked against on page-load, to see if it needs to reload the ACL information.

Comment: I would bump you if I could. I'm in essentially the same boat. Storing the ACL in a file (as per the documentation) seeme a little sketchy. Can you edit this question if you've found any better ways to do this?

Comment: I currently haven't found a suitable solution for this. It is a shame this post hasn't received more commenting, as I do think it is quite an interesting question.

I guess the answer is to store it in a database, and then cache it? It would be good to have some clarification on the merits of this, and if not, what the alternative would be.

Comment: Yes Monarch you question is really great and very frequently asked by the phalcon user.
Even I were looking for the same kind of solution that i do not find any where yet. 
I tried to write some custom code to make the ACL dynamic using the DB, but still struggling with it.

Please guide if you have achieved the same. @TheMonarch

Answer (score 1):

Yes @TheMmonarch you question is really great and very frequently asked by the `phalcon` user. Even I were looking for the same kind of solution that i do not find any where yet. I tried to write some custom code to make the ACL dynamic using the DB, but still struggling with it.

I were surfing lot of sites and blog then finally I come across with such DB structure which could be helpful to build such kind of system.

```
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(`name`)
);
CREATE TABLE `access_list` (
  `roles_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `resources_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `access_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `allowed` INT(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`roles_name`, `resources_name`, `access_name`)
);

CREATE TABLE `resources` (
  `name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(`name`)
);

CREATE TABLE `resources_accesses` (
  `resources_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `access_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`resources_name`, `access_name`)
);

CREATE TABLE `roles_inherits` (
  `roles_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `roles_inherit` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(roles_name, roles_inherit)
);
```

Any suggestion or change would be appreciate!!!

Comment: Any enhancement or implementation on this? if yes, do share, if possible